# Examples of misquotes resulting in costly lawsuits?

Tags: intellectual-property, academia

I'm looking for examples of misquotes resulting in expensive lawsuits or at least embarrassing retractions or otherwise costly or cumbersome consequences.

This includes misquotes that resulted in a change in meaning, where the quoted party sued to have the misquote retracted or corrected.

By 'misquote' I don't just mean putting words in someone's mouth, but more so the technical definition where a quote doesn't rise to the level of academic standards, eg because additions and/or omissions aren't properly indicated. Sometimes, even 'innocent' mistakes like moving or removing a comma can change the meaning significantly.

Bonus points for big cases that resulted in public notoriety. For example, a big news outlet misquoting someone and having to defend themselves in court.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/90629/what-is-plagiarism-legally

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm asking about misquotes not plagiarism.

Comment: @DennsHackethal The emphasis on "academic standards" and concern about attribution suggested otherwise. Misquotation is rarely a basis of legal liability. Mere embarrassment is not a legal issue.

Comment: @ohwilleke "The emphasis on 'academic standards' and concern about attribution suggested otherwise." No. Academic standards include rules for proper quoting. And putting words in someone's mouth (the "concern about attribution" you seem to reference) isn't necessarily plagiarism.

Comment: Rules about plagiarism are the main part of the rules about quoting. One of the main purposes of plagiarism rules is to be clear about who really said what or had which idea. More generally, the concern is lack of context in the question. Law is a highly context specific thing, it doesn't have broad general answers. So, knowing what kind of fact patterns are contemplated is very helpful. Academic standards play no role in any legal tests in the U.S., while they do in the exclusively academic domain of plagiarism.

Comment: If you alter a quote but keep the correct attribution it's still a misquote but not plagiarism. [Here's](https://quote-differ.herokuapp.com/diffs/ayn-rand-institute-misquoting-ayn-rand-s-of-living-death) an example (site is mine) where the linked quoter attributes properly but still badly misquotes by altering the quote without the requisite indications. My question simply isn't about plagiarism (and couldn't have been since I knew before posting it that plagiarism generally isn't legally actionable in the US, as you write in your answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

**Overview**

> I'm looking for examples of misquotes resulting in expensive lawsuits.
> . . . For example, a big news outlet misquoting someone and having to
> defend themselves in court.

**I am not aware of any such lawsuits in modern U.S. law** (i.e., in the last sixty years), and have no reason to believe that there are any such lawsuits. And, in particular, an "innocent" misquotation by a reporter is essentially never actionable in court, even if it results in a change of meaning.

There have been a couple of notable cases alleging misquotation in this era, but they have all been resounding defeats for the person alleging that they were misquoted.

In the most notable case in the last three decades alleging misquotation, the case of the person alleging that they were misquoted was dismissed at the outset, and the person bringing the lawsuit was sanctioned for bringing the lawsuit at all, so in the end, it cost the defendants nothing.

Misquoting someone is rarely a basis for legal liability in the United States. And, the mere fact that someone is misquoted, in and of itself, is not illegal or a basis for legal liability.

> This includes misquotes that resulted in a change in meaning, where
> the quoted party sued to have the misquote retracted or corrected.

Absent the narrow circumstances described below, there is no legal duty to correct or retract a misquotation in U.S. law.

Some states allow defamation defendants to use a correction or retraction as an affirmative defense to defamation liability or as a limitation on the damages that can be awarded for defamation, but statutes even creating this incentive to correct or retract inaccurate statements or quotations are a minority position. A state by state summary of the retraction statutes of the 17 states that have them (roughly a third of U.S. states) can be found [here](https://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/state-law-retractions).

Also, as a practical matter, if a statement was not recorded or in writing, proving that it was misquoted is often difficult or impossible.

It is quite common for people to say something other than what they meant to say (or something that they regret having said) and then to claim that they were misquoted, when they weren't. *See, e.g.,* Republican Presidential candidate Vivek Ramaswamy's [false claim](https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2023/08/23/fact-check-vivek-ramaswamy-the-atlantic-911-quote-collins-src-vpx.cnn) on CNN that *The Atlantic* misquoted him.

Most misquotations either retain the thrust of the original statement, but not its exact wording, or misattribute the person who said it, neither of which give rise to legal liability. Unintentional misquotations are likewise much more common than intentional ones.

**Possible defamation liability**

Generally, to give rise to defamation liability, the misquotation:

1. Must be shared with someone other than the person who made the statement, and:
2. Damage the reputation of the person quoted in a way that it wouldn't if it was properly quoted, and
3. The person making the statement knows that it is misquotation or acts with reckless disregard for the truth or falsity of the statement.

Unless the misquotation leads to something that counts as [libel *per se*](https://www.findlaw.com/injury/torts-and-personal-injuries/what-is-defamation-per-se-.html), the person suing would also have to show actual damages, rather than having harm presumed as a matter of law. The four categories of libel *per se* are:

- Saying that someone committed a crime or immoral conduct
- Saying that someone had a contagious, infectious, or "loathsome" disease
- Saying someone engaged in sexual misconduct or was unchaste
- Saying something harmful about someone's business, trade, or profession

Misquotations are less likely to constitute libel *per se* than affirmative statements about a person, because they are less likely to be about one of these four things.

As [the leading law review article](https://scholarship.law.vanderbilt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2539&context=vlr) on the question of misquotation liability explains:

> To quote or not to quote' is no longer a valid question in defamation
> law because courts have lessened the burden on writers to use the
> exact words of the speaker in quoted language. If individuals feel
> that the press has misquoted them, they have three realistic options:
> First, ignore the misquotation; second, contact the media and request
> a retraction; and third, file a lawsuit claiming defamation and
> seeking monetary damages.' The first alternative is the easiest, but
> given the emotional overtones of defamation, it is also the most
> unlikely. If the media were more sensitive and less defensive, the
> second alternative might be the best solution. For many individuals,
> however, a lawsuit appears to be the only way to obtain satisfaction.
>
> Yet if the individual elects to file a lawsuit, the truth or falsity
> of the quotation will be far down the list of factors addressed by the
> court and may not be addressed at all. Plaintiffs in a defamation suit
> first must weave their way through the maze of categories that the
> courts have erected. The most pressing questions include: (1) Is the
> plaintiff a public official, a public figure, or a private figure; (2)
> Did the plaintiff bring suit against a media defendant or a nonmedia
> defendant; (3) Does the quoted language concern an issue of public or
> private concern; and (4) Can the plaintiff prove actual malice by the
> defendant? Doctrines such as the libel-proof plaintiff and neutral
> reportage also must be considered. Because the answers to these
> questions usually are unclear, commentators in the field have
> described defamation law as contradictory and confusing'" and a
> "hodge-podge that operates erratically at best, and perversely at
> worst."

One of the leading cases applying defamation law in the misquotation context and reaching these conclusions is *Masson v. New Yorker Magazine*, 895 F.2d 1535 (9th Cir. 1989). As the law review article cited above explains:

> the court summarized the current law governing defamatory
> misquotations as follows: (1) actual malice may be inferred from a
> fabricated quotation that is wholly a product of the author's
> imagination; (2) actual malice will not be inferred when the quoted
> language, although not in the exact words of the speaker, represents a
> rational interpretation of the speaker's ambiguous statements; and (3)
> actual malice will not be inferred when the misquoted language does
> not alter the substantive content of the speaker's unambiguous
> statements.

This was affirmed on other grounds in *Masson v. New Yorker Magazine*, 111 S. Ct. 2419, 2429 (1991), which, [according to one law review article](https://repository.uclawsf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1326&context=hastings_comm_ent_law_journal), "rejected the Ninth Circuit's test of rational interpretation and substituted its own test of material alteration."

This case basically just reaffirmed the holding of *New York Times v. Sullivan*, 376 U.S. 254 (1964), in which the U.S. Supreme Court established the "actual malice" standard for most defamation lawsuits.

In many cases, bringing a lawsuit alleging that you have been misquoted will causes the person suing to have legal liability to the person sued, even if the person sued actually did misquote them, under state statutes discouraging strategic lawsuits against public participation (a.k.a. "SLAPPs"). Anti-SLAPP statutes also provide strong procedural protections to defendants in defamation actions. A state by state survey of anti-SLAPP statutes can be found [here](https://www.ifs.org/research/anti-slapp-statutes-a-report-card/).

This is precisely what happened in the case of [*Paul Brodeur v. Atlas Entertainment*](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/court/ca-court-of-appeal/1740212.html) (Cal. App. 2016), which is arguably the most prominent misquotation case in the post-*New York Times v. Sullivan* era. The California Court of Appeals summarized Brodeur's lawsuit as follows:

> He alleged causes of action for libel, defamation, slander and false
> light, asserting that he had never made the quoted statement, and that
> by misquoting him, defendants “have suggested to the movie audience
> that Mr. Brodeur made a scientifically unsupportable statement,”
> damaging his reputation.

This lawsuit was dismissed promptly on a motion to dismiss, shortly after the lawsuit was filed, and Mr. Brodeur was sanctioned for bringing a frivolous lawsuit, in the trial court. The California Court of Appeals affirmed this outcome.

Often, defamation lawsuits also have very short statutes of limitation. For example, in Colorado, the statute of limitations is one year from the time that the person suing learns that the statement was made.

A handful of cases of recognized that "[false light invasion of privacy](https://repository.uclawsf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1326&context=hastings_comm_ent_law_journal)" can be a basis of a civil lawsuit, but only minority of states recognize this legal theory, and in many of those that do, it is virtually indistinguishable from defamation.

[Another law review article](https://repository.uclawsf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1326&context=hastings_comm_ent_law_journal) is entitled "The Right To Misquote" which fairly sums up the predominant rule of U.S. law. (The article argues for a new and separate basis to bring a lawsuit for misquotation even if it is not defamatory, which was never adopted by any U.S. court.)

**Perjury and fraud**

An intentional misquotation could sometimes constitute perjury (if made under oath) or fraud, if it is used with an intent to deceive, if the misquotation implies some material fact, if it was reasonable to believe the statement was true, and if belief that the statement is true actually harm someone if people hearing it believe it to be true.

**Negligent misrepresentation**

A negligent misquotation would only give rise to liability when it is made in the course of the business or occupation of the person misquoting, the mistake is not one that someone would make if they exercised reasonable care, it was reasonable to rely upon the second hand quotation, and it caused economic harm to the person relying upon it. This would be rare.

**Contract disputes**

"Innocent" misquotation is almost never a basis for a lawsuit except when, perhaps, it results in an erroneous contract term (e.g., someone orders 5 hamburgers and this gets processed as 500 hamburgers), or erroneous contract performance (e.g., putting the wrong words in an advertisement paid for by the person quoted).

**Intellectual property**

Misquoting someone is basically never an intellectual property violation of any kind. It will almost never violate a copyright, a trademark, a trade name, a patent, a trade secret, or a right of publicity.

**Professional ethics for lawyers**

One notable exception to the general rule is that intentionally, or even negligently misquoting statements made by others in documents filed in courts can constitute a professional ethics violation for lawyers.

In practice, however, more serious sanctions for these professional ethics violations, such as a suspension of a license to practice law or disbarment, as opposed to a public warning to the attorney, or an attorneys' fee award in a particular lawsuit for bringing groundless claims, would be very rare absent facts amounting to the "actual malice" standard in defamation cases.

For example, misquotations were among [the myriad instances of gross disregard for the facts in the legal documents filed by Rudy Giuliani](https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/rudy-giuliani-lose-law-license-false-election-claims-rcna62092) in an attempt to overturn the results of the 2020 Presidential election that have led to challenges to his law license.

Those statements were immune from civil liability in lawsuits for money damages, however, under litigation privileges from defamation liability.

**Non-legal matters**

Other embarrassing retractions or otherwise costly or cumbersome consequences, are not legal matters.

Academic dishonestly, plagiarism, or carelessness are generally not legally actionable in the United States, although it might cause a body that awarded a prize to, outside the context of the law, revoke a honor or prize, and might be properly considered when considering a candidate for an academic job.

**Caveat: The U.S. may be exceptional**

U.S. law regarding misquotations is heavily covered by strong protections for the freedom of speech and the freedom of the press in the U.S. Bill of Rights.

Not all non-U.S. jurisdictions are as protective of the "Right to Misquote".

For example, [Israel appears to recognize](https://www.timesofisrael.com/in-latest-lawsuit-yair-netanyahu-sued-for-misquoting-journalists-remarks/) a legal cause of action for misquotation. [So does Germany](https://globalfreedomofexpression.columbia.edu/cases/kunast-v-facebook/), under the rubric of a person's "general right of personality."

Comment: Mind that the German case you cite is not about accidental misquotes as per the question, which I would guess would be covered by libel laws in the US.